# QBSDK - UK 2013 Ignoring TaxRegistrationNumber on CustomerAdd Request

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml, qbfc

QuickBooks UK 2013 - SDK is ignoring TaxRegistrationNumber field.  If you look at the request below we are setting TaxRegistrationNumber however it is being ignored as shown in the response.

Here is outgoing XML

```
`
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE QBXML PUBLIC '-//INTUIT//DTD QBXML QBD 12.0//EN' >
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError = "continueOnError">
    <CustomerAddRq requestID = "1">
      <CustomerAdd>
        <Name>AAA Euro</Name>
        <IsActive>1</IsActive>
        <BillAddress>
          <Addr1></Addr1>
          <Addr2></Addr2>
          <Addr3></Addr3>
          <Addr4></Addr4>
          <Addr5></Addr5>
          <City></City>
          <State></State>
          <PostalCode></PostalCode>
          <Country></Country>
        </BillAddress>
        <ShipAddress>
          <Addr1></Addr1>
          <Addr2></Addr2>
          <Addr3></Addr3>
          <Addr4></Addr4>
          <Addr5></Addr5>
          <City></City>
          <State></State>
          <PostalCode></PostalCode>
          <Country></Country>
        </ShipAddress>
        <SalesTaxCodeRef>
          <FullName>E</FullName>
        </SalesTaxCodeRef>
        <SalesTaxCountry>UK</SalesTaxCountry>
        <TaxRegistrationNumber>230 161 818</TaxRegistrationNumber>
        <CurrencyRef>
          <FullName>British Pound Sterling</FullName>
        </CurrencyRef>
      </CustomerAdd>
    </CustomerAddRq>
  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
`
```

Here is return XML - Note TaxRegistrationNumber is missing

```
`
<QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRs>
<CustomerAddRs requestID="1" statusCode="0" statusSeverity="Info" statusMessage="Status OK">
<CustomerRet>
<ListID>8000000F-1374158926</ListID>
<TimeCreated>2013-07-18T10:48:46-05:00</TimeCreated>
<TimeModified>2013-07-18T10:48:46-05:00</TimeModified>
<EditSequence>1374158926</EditSequence>
<Name>AAA Euro</Name>
<FullName>AAA Euro</FullName>
<IsActive>true</IsActive>
<Sublevel>0</Sublevel>
<Balance>0.00</Balance>
<TotalBalance>0.00</TotalBalance>
<SalesTaxCodeRef>
<ListID>80000007-1350563554</ListID>
<FullName>E</FullName>
</SalesTaxCodeRef>
<SalesTaxCountry>UK</SalesTaxCountry>
<JobStatus>None</JobStatus>
<PreferredDeliveryMethod>None</PreferredDeliveryMethod>
<CurrencyRef>
<ListID>80000016-1350563181</ListID>
<FullName>British Pound Sterling</FullName>
</CurrencyRef>
</CustomerRet>
</CustomerAddRs>
</QBXMLMsgsRs>
</QBXML>
`
```

Comment: Seeing the same thing, checking with development on whether this is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced times when not everything I sent over was returned on the response. Have you verified if the elements updated in QB or not?

I would add the following to my request to force a return of the element.

```
 <IncludeRetElement >TaxRegistrationNumber</IncludeRetElement>
```